# add hidden elements to table view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm new to iOS development and I have being able to solve most of the problems I have, but now I got some requirements and I'm not really sure how to configure it in the interface builder to get the result I need.

Requirements:

1. Navigation Bar (inherit)
2. Search bar (visible when swipe down)
3. Label message and Button (visible when swipe down)
4. Table view
5. Tab Bar (inherit)

I started by adding a table view controller to my storyboard, and I'm being able to populate the table view. So I have:

Table view controller

1. Navigation Bar (inherit)
2. Table view
3. Tab Bar (inherit)

But now I have no idea how to modify the table view controller to add the hidden search bar and the hidden label and button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a UITableView contains a Header section where you can drop elements in. It solves my first problem. Now I'm trying to hide the header section.